# Drop shadow on every side of a borderless form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a Form that has `FormBorderStyle` set to `None`. I've overridden `ClientParams` and added `0x20000` to the `ClassStyle`. This gives me a `form` with drop shadow on the right and bottom edges.

If you look at a form with `FormBorderStyle` set to `Fixed3D` then it has a drop shadow on every side, is it possible to do this with `FormBorderStyle` set to `None`?